# Lightsail instance connection to Lightsail database is unreliable

Tags: mysql, mariadb, lamp, amazon-lightsail

I have a web app running on Lightsail instances stacked with LAMP (PHP 7/MariaDB 10 service). When I want to connect the instances to a Lightsail database instead of localhost, it works sporadically. The front end reads "cannot connect to MySQL database" and in the database server log I read : `[MY-010055] [Server] IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known" where the IP is the private IP address of my instance.`

My instances and database are in the same region. Even though it is not necessary I have tried enabling VPC peering and opening the db to the public.

**I can connect to the database using the command line tool**: mysql -u uuuu -p -h hhhhh (ie: it is not a problem with entering the wrong credentials)

**The web app seems to work with the dedicated Lightsail db server when I am the only one using it**  and until I open it to more traffic, then I get the connection error.

I have increased the number of max_connections from 65 to 500 using the aws CLI (localhost is 150). My current traffic is 2000 visitors per day.

```
aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name Database-1 --parameters "parameterName=max_connections,parameterValue=500,applyMethod=immediate"
```

Localhost is Mariadb 10, dedicated database server is MySQL 8

SSL is handled by Cloudflare. There's no SSL on my instance.

I don't want to keep using localhost dbs, I want to centralize my data in a dedicated database.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: The message in the database server log is not an error, just a warning. You can disable it by putting `skip-name-resolve` in your my.cnf.

Comment: I have created an RDS Mariadb database in AWS and connected it to my Lightsail instances. Everything is working fine now.